# Is it okay to have a self canceling $timeout?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I am wondering if it's okay to have a `$timeout` that cancels itself after it runs. Usually what I see is people saying that you should cancel your `$timeout`'s in the `$destroy` like this:

```
var timeout = $timeout(function () {
    // stuff
});

$scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
    $timeout.cancel(timeout);
});
```

But, is it okay to do this instead:

```
var timeout = $timeout(function () {
    // stuff
    $timeout.cancel(timeout);
});
```

Comment: Your proposed "is it OK" code tries to cancel the timeout after it has already run. At that point there's nothing to cancel. The point of cancelling inside the `$destroy` event handler would be to prevent an outstanding scheduled timeout from running after the destroy.

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense, I think you're looking for interval or something like that, then it might make sense. Timeout will run your function in given amount of seconds, inside that function your code is effective just as empty line or return statement since seconds already passed - in your case 0 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn and pegla. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

When the DOM element is removed from the page,
AngularJS will trigger the $destroy event on
the scope. This gives us a chance to cancel any
pending timer that we may have.

**$timeout() returns a promise object. This object can be supplied to $timeout.cancel() function to cancel the timeout.**

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    $timeout.cancel(promise);
});
```